# My Site, adding to "Ask Me About" returns "The given term is not valid"

Tags: my-site, term-store, mysite, mysites, my

I have a SP2010 "My Site". When a user edits their profile, in the "Ask Me About" section, there is a semicolon-separated list of terms which the user is supposed to populate. The problem is, though, the user types in some phrase or word, and the result gets "red-lined" and if they try to submit, they get a "The given term is not valid" validation notice in red.

Looking in `Central Admin > Manage Service Application> User Profile Service Application > Manage User Properties > Ask Me About`; I do see a "Pick a Term Set for this property" dropdown menu. The dropdown menu contains:

- (blank)
- Community
- Project Keywords
- Documents
- Wiki Categories (repteated 30+ times)

I'm not sure if this "Term Set" setting even is involved, but the problem does seem to stem from an attempted and failed lookup into a term set somewhere.

Fwiw, I have looked [this forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cc78d6c7-d415-48c9-bbb2-4d9ceafb1d3d/sp-2010-adding-skills-interests-and-ask-me-about-to-mysite-profile-invalid-term?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) and per the commentary, did verify the settings are as expected.

So with that, does anybody have a suggestion on what I need to change to allow people to add in their own text into the `"Ask Me About"` without getting hassled about the term not being valid?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Do you already have an solution?

Comment: No, I did not. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Term Set and select that Term Set in the "Pick a Term Set for this property" dropdown. Users are only allowed to pick terms from the term set you've set in the "Pick a Term Set for this property" dropdown. This term set could/should contain work related items e.g. "Excel", "Math", "Biology", "History" etc.

Working with managed metadat: https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/working-with-managed-metadata.cfm